# Codeigniter 4 Pagination is working, however, my bootstrap 4 template for pagination is not

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-4

I am using CI4.  I have successfully implemented pagination.  I have 9 posts and have used '3' to paginate and therefore 3 pages.  Everything works well but the css is terrible.  Here is a pict of the pagination.  Not the page count which is correct.

[image]

I therefore was to add boostrap 4 css to CI's pagination.  When I add boostrap 4's pagination, it only show 1 page.  The css is in bs4 formatting but the page just shows '1'.  Here is a pict:

[image]

This is my controller:

```
class Post extends BaseController
{

function __construct(){
    $this->PostModel        = new \App\Models\PostModel;    
    $this->CategoryModel    = new \App\Models\CategoryModel;
}

function index(){
    $post_category_id = null;
    $category_is_published = 1;
    $post_is_published = 1; 
    $pagination = 1;  // this is just to tell the model to return $this instead of the results.
    $this->data['posts']    = $this->PostModel->getPostsByCategory($post_category_id, 
                              $category_is_published, $post_is_published, $pagination )->paginate(3);
    $this->data['pager']    = $this->PostModel->pager;
    return view('Post/post_index', $this->data);
}

}//end controller
```

This is my view file (I have shortened it, of course).  `$pager->links()` will display the right number of pages but when I add the bootstrap 4 template, like below, it only displays one page.

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) :  ?>
    <p class="card-text"> <?php echo word_limiter($post->post_body, 30); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?= $pager->links('bootstrap', 'bootstrap4_pagination'); ?>
```

and this is my bootstrap4_pagination template;

```
<?php $pager->setSurroundCount(4); ?>
<nav>
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php if ($pager->hasPrevious()) { ?>
        <li class="page-item">
             <a href="<?= $pager->getFirst() ?>" aria-label="First" class="page-link">
                <span aria-hidden="true">First</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a href="<?= $pager->getPrevious() ?>" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                <span>&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 
        foreach ($pager->links() as $link) { 
            $activeclass = $link['active']?'active':'';
    ?>
        <li class="page-item <?= $activeclass ?>">
            <a href="<?= $link['uri'] ?>" class="page-link">
                <?= $link['title'] ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($pager->hasNext()) { ?>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a href="<?= $pager->getNext() ?>" aria-label="Next" class="page-link">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
             <a href="<?= $pager->getLast() ?>" aria-label="Last" class="page-link">
                <span aria-hidden="true">Last</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think you need to look at. https://thephpcode.com/blog/view/styling-codeigniter-pagination-with-bootstrap-4.html

Comment: No, that is Codeigniter 3.  It is very different in CI4.

Comment: Did you add your template *bootstrap4_pagination* to app/Config/Pager.php file?    

```public $templates = ['bootstrap4_pagination'=>'path/to/the/view'];```

Comment: Yes, I did.  If you see above, it is not a case of not reading the template.  clearly the BS4 template is being read and the pagination displays.  See the picts.  For some reason though only 1 page shows in the pagination.

Comment: Just wondering, did you post this on the CI forums at all? I know the devs do watch those boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified that you want to use the `bootstrap` group:

`<?= $pager->links('bootstrap', 'bootstrap4_pagination'); ?>`

But you're not creating a `bootstrap` group:

`$this->data['posts']    = $this->PostModel->getPostsByCategory($post_category_id,  $category_is_published, $post_is_published, $pagination )->paginate(3);`

This should be:

`$this->data['posts']    = $this->PostModel->getPostsByCategory($post_category_id,  $category_is_published, $post_is_published, $pagination )->paginate(3, 'bootstrap');`

Alternatively you could leave out the group and replace `bootstrap` with `default`:

`<?= $pager->links('default', 'bootstrap4_pagination'); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

`app\Config\Pager.php`

```
public array $templates = [
    'default_full' => 'CodeIgniter\Pager\Views\default_full',
    'default_simple' => 'CodeIgniter\Pager\Views\default_simple',
    'default_head' => 'CodeIgniter\Pager\Views\default_head',
    'my_pagination' => 'App\Views\Pager\my_pagination',
];
```

and I created a view file `app\Views\Pager\my_pagination.php` (Bootstrap 4)

```
            <?php $pager->setSurroundCount(4); ?>
            <nav>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <?php if ($pager->hasPrevious()) { ?>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a href="<?= $pager->getFirst() ?>" aria-label="First" class="page-link">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">First</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a href="<?= $pager->getPrevious() ?>" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                            <span>&laquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php 
                    foreach ($pager->links() as $link) { 
                        $activeclass = $link['active']?'active':'';
                ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?= $activeclass ?>">
                        <a href="<?= $link['uri'] ?>" class="page-link">
                            <?= $link['title'] ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if ($pager->hasNext()) { ?>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a href="<?= $pager->getNext() ?>" aria-label="Next" class="page-link">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a href="<?= $pager->getLast() ?>" aria-label="Last" class="page-link">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">Last</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            </nav>
```

Then to use, I wrote the controller like below:

```
    $data = [
        'result' => $model->paginate(25),
        'headers_col' => $model->getFieldNames('my_table_name'),
        'pager' => $model->pager,
    ];
```

and in the view like below:

```
 <?= $pager->links('default', 'my_pagination') ?>
```

and I got the result like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I kinda had this challenge as well while using Tailwind for styling. Below will come in handy for someone in the future:

This is my custom pagination view found in `./public/views/Pager/tailwindcss_pagination.css`

```
<?php

use CodeIgniter\Pager\PagerRenderer;

/**
 * @var PagerRenderer $pager
 */
$pager->setSurroundCount(2);
?>

<nav aria-label="<?= lang('Pager.pageNavigation') ?>">
    <div class="join">
    <?php if ($pager->hasPrevious()) : ?>
        <a href="<?= $pager->getFirst() ?>" class="join-item btn" aria- 
label="<?= lang('Pager.first') ?>">
        <span aria-hidden="true"><?= lang('Pager.first') ?></span>
    </a>
    <a href="<?= $pager->getPrevious() ?>" class="join-item btn" aria- 
   label="<?= lang('Pager.previous') ?>">
        <span aria-hidden="true"><?= lang('Pager.previous') ?></span>
    </a>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php foreach ($pager->links() as $link) : ?>
    <a href="<?= $link['uri'] ?>" class="join-item btn <?= $link['active'] 
? 'btn-active btn-primary' : '' ?>">
        <?= $link['title'] ?>
    </a>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php if ($pager->hasNext()) : ?>
        <a href="<?= $pager->getNext() ?>" class="join-item btn" aria- 
   label="<?= lang('Pager.next') ?>">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><?= lang('Pager.next') ?></span>
        </a>
        <a href="<?= $pager->getLast() ?>" class="join-item btn" aria- 
   label="<?= lang('Pager.last') ?>">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><?= lang('Pager.last') ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
</nav>
```

CodeIgniter 4 Config: `Pager.php - app\Config\`

```
 `'tailwind_pagination' => 'App\Views\Pager\Tailwindcss_pagination'
];`
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
`$data['staff'] = $this->staff_model->paginate(20);
    $data['pager'] = $this->staff_model->pager;`
```

I think the technique like @Mohammed suggested is to replace the first parameter in `$pager->link()` to 'default'

[image]